# onDraw event in react-chartist

Tags: reactjs, events, chartist.js

In another forum I found this code which can be usefull for me:

```
var chart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['Test', 'Long test', 'Very long test'],
  series: [[1, 5, 3]]
});

// Uncomment this line to test rendering without foreign objects
//chart.supportsForeignObject = false;

chart.on('draw', function(event) {
  // If the draw event is for labels on the x-axis
  if(event.type === 'label' && event.axis.units.pos === 'x') {
    // If foreign object is NOT supported, we need to fallback to text-anchor and event.width / 2 offset.
    if(!chart.supportsForeignObject) {
      event.element.attr({
        x: event.x + event.width / 2,
        'text-anchor': 'middle'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The special problem which is solved with that isn't the important thing. My problem is I don't use `new Chartist.Bar` to declare a new chartist component as I use react-chartist:

```
<ChartistGraph
          data={graphData}
          options={graphOptions}
          type={type}
/>
```

So I cannot react on the onDraw event as in the example.
Is it possible to bind a function to the onDraw event? I tried something like this:

```
<ChartistGraph
          onDraw={e => onDrawHandler(e)}
          data={graphData}
          options={graphOptions}
          type={type}
/>
```

which didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `listener` prop:

```
<ChartistGraph
    listener={{
        draw: e => onDrawHandler(e)
    }}
    data={graphData}
    options={graphOptions}
    type={type}
/>
```

See: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist/issues/27

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to stop the chart from re-drawing again and again on window resize and onclick events in reactjs?

Comment: I, too, would like to know how to stop the redraw on window resizing.  It also happens using plain JavaScript.

Comment: I found a possible solution [here] (https://github.com/chartist-js/chartist/issues/992)

Comment: I ended up switching over to chart.js and couldn't be happier with it.  By default, it doesn't redraw the screen when resizing the window, plus the charts look a lot more professional.  The community appears to be larger, also, which will help when searching for answers.